# Import multiple tables from multiple mdb files into excel or Power BI?

Tags: excel, powerbi

Is it possible to import multiple tables from multiple .mdb files into excel or power BI?
My .mdb files have tables which are in the same structure.

Ex.
first_file.mdb contains table A, table B
second_file.mdb contains table A2, table B2
table A and table A2 has same structure, so as B and B2

When I tried, excel only allow to import multiple table when select only 1 mdb file, but when import as folder (multiple mdb files), multiple table selection mode is gone.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Power Query it is totally possible. Once the files are displayed in the Power Query DataGrid, the 'Content' column will list the (same) object that should be worked on in each of the files. You will have to adapt the proper reading of the objects within the query steps. The M code below can be your start to do this. (note that the folder location must be changed here, to suit your scenario and that only ".mdb" files are allowed in this sample):

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\YourUserName\Desktop\Access"),
    #"Lowercased Text" = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Extension", Text.Lower, type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Lowercased Text", each [Extension] = ".mdb")
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```